# Mixing PHP variable with quotes on a string literal

Tags: php

I'm trying to add " " on a php variable,

What i have:

```
$id = 123;
echo "{$id}"; //123
```

How can i return "123" instead of just 123?

```
echo ""{$id}""; //adding extra columns is not working
```

Answer (score 4):

You escape the double quotes you want in the string with the `\` backslash, like this:

```
$id = 123;
echo "\"{$id}\"";
```

Comment: Yes, I agree, this question has been asked before, but so have most other questions. This is however a very basic one, and doing only a bit of research would have retrieved the answer. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask